# Show only consecutive observations that changed in one column by group

Tags: sas, dataset, rows

I have the below dataset, I would like to show only the consecutive rows that Centre_code changed per Contract_No by Customer.

DATASET 1

```
  Date Customer Contract_No Centre_code
    09Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
    10Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
    11Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 102
    09Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA5678 102
    10Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA5678 102
    11Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA5678 319
    09Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB1234 515
    10Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB1234 515
    11Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB1234 515
    09Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB11878 511
    10Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB11878 511
    11Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB11878 515
    10Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB48741 511
    10Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB48741 511
    11Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB48741 515
```

DATASET 2

```
Date Customer Contract_No Centre_code
10-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
11-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
12-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
13-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
14-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
15-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
16-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
17-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
18-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
19-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
20-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
21-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
22-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 102
```

Desire Output DATASET 1

```
Date Customer Contract_No Centre_code
10Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
11Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 102
10Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA5678 102
11Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA5678 319
10Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB11878 511
11Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB11878 515
10Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB48741 511
11Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB48741 515
```

Desire Output DATASET 2

```
   Date Customer Contract_No Centre_code
    21-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
    22-Jul-19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 102
```

Comment: Have you written any code? Are you getting any error messages? SO is not a code writing service.  Why is `10Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA5678 102` in the output ? The center code is the same as the prior row.  Are you really looking for changes in center by customer+contract, effectively wanting examination of contiguous groups of customer+contract+center and selecting the row of `first.` occurence ? Are you writing SQL or Data Step ?  In data step have you used `BY` statements with `NOTSORTED` before ?

Comment: I am using Date step however it is not returning the expected output. and for your question, for AAAAA5678 , until 10Jul19 the Centre_code is 102 and on 11Jul19 it changed to 319. This kind of alteration I would like to show in my reports.

Comment: Why is this row not in desired output ?  `09Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB1234 515`, or perhaps `11Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB1234 515`

Comment: Because the Centre_code doesn't changed. if you noticed, the desired output only shows the lines that there are changes in Centre_code column for 2 consecutive date. Contract_no BBBBB1234 doesnt have any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the NOTSORTED keyword on the BY statement.

```
data have;
  length Date 8 Customer $8 Contract_No $20 Center_code 8;
  input Date Customer Contract_No Center_code ;
  informat date date.;
  format date date9.;
cards;
09Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
10Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 319
11Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA1234 102
09Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA5678 102
10Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA5678 102
11Jul19 AAAAA AAAAA5678 319
09Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB1234 515
10Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB1234 515
11Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB1234 515
09Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB11878 511
10Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB11878 511
11Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB11878 515
10Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB48741 511
10Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB48741 511
11Jul19 BBBBB BBBBB48741 515
;

data want;
 set have;
 by customer contract_no Center_code notsorted;
 if last.Center_code;
run;
```

Result:
[image]

From the comments it sounds like instead of listing where there is a change to center code you want to list ALL CENTERS when there is ANY change.  One way to do that is to check if the center code is ever different from the first center code.  You can implement that with two DO loops. One to test for changes and one to output the records when there is a change.  We can continue to still check the LAST.CENTER_CODE flag just in case the same center code appears for multiple dates in a row.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by customer contract_no date center_code;
run;

data want;
  do until(last.contract_no);
    set have;
    by customer contract_no ;
    if first.contract_no then first_center=center_code;
    if center_code ne first_center then change=1;
  end;
  do until(last.contract_no);
    set have;
    by customer contract_no center_code notsorted;
    if change and last.center_code then output;
  end;
run;
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: Your code works fine, but I would like to get the two consecutive date where there are Centre_code changed. The codes also shows for example the BBBBB1234 Contract_No. though it doesn't changed the Centre_code.

Comment: It is easier to detect changes when they first occur.  So is it ok to get the first date for the new contract instead of the last date?

Comment: Updated answer to include a method to identify the contracts with multiple centers.

Comment: Thanks for the codes Tom, however if there's any way instead of the first date, I would like show the last date of the previous Centre_code is before it change to the new Centre_code. As what I am trying to show in my report is when the changes happened and not the first it occur. I added DATASET 2 in my question so you can visualize what I am trying to explain here. The desire output for DATASET 2 is also there.

Comment: Listing the last date before the change in some ways should be enough. To really flag the last record before a change and the first record after a change would require checking both previous value of CENTER and next value of CENTER.  The next value of CENTER is the hard thing to do, but it can be done. Search for example SAS questions implementing the LEAD equivalent of the LAG() function.

Comment: Hi Tom, I tried to search as what you mentioned but got confused it shows so many approach. I am just using SAS for less than 2 months so somehow my understanding is not much but will try to understand the LAG fxn. However if you can help me to resolve this query will greatly appreciate. Somewhat your code is almost what I am looking for but I need to show the last date before the Code got changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If by

> consecutive rows that Center_code changed

you mean you want to see the observation before the change and the observation after the change you can just use the FIRST.CENTER_CODE and LAST.CENTER_CODE flags. (Make sure to use NOTSORTED keyword since records are sorted by DATE, not CENTER_CODE within the CONTRACT_NO values.) If you also eliminate the first observation for the first center code and the last observation for the last center code then you will only get contracts where there is at least one change.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  by customer contract_no center_code notsorted ;
  if (last.center_code and not last.contract_no) 
     or (first.center_code and not first.contract_no)
  ;
run;
```